# pass the values of three vectors into another sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub as follows:

```
 Sub simulations(k As Long)
 Dim moAkt() As Double, moShort() As Double, moImmo() As Double
    .
    .
    .
    For l = 1 To length
    .
    .
              ' write into the vectors
                moAkt(l) = zaktie
                moImmo(l) = zImmo
                moShort(l) = zshort
    Next l
    End Sub
```

I call this sub in another sub `calculateColl`

```
  Sub calculateColl
Call simulations
               Dim l As Long
                 Open "C\testfile.txt" For Append As #1
                   For l = 1 To 10
                     Print #1, moImmo(l) ";" zshort(l) ";" moAkt(l)
                     Print #1,
                   Next l
                    Close #1
    End Sub
```

so I get an error because these vectors are not known in this sub. Now I want to **avoid** `ByRef` since I have another variable in my `sub`. How can I pass the values of all these three vectors into the new sub `calculateColl` so that I can write them in a file?

Comment: Were are `moAkt`, `moImmo`, and `moShort` declared?

Comment: your `simulations` Sub asks for one parameter (namely `k As Long`), so you can't call it like `Call simulations` without passing a long variable or literal

Comment: If `moAkt`, `moImmo` and `moShort` are in the sub `calculateColl`, pass them `byRef` to the sub `simulations`

Comment: furthermore to @user3598756's comment. you don't even use the variable `k` in `simulations` sub

Comment: @Comintern: 'Dim moAkt() As Double, moShort() As Double, moImmo() As Double'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Sub simulations` should really be a function if you want to return values from it. There are a bunch of options as to what to return (a `Collection`, a 2D array, etc.).  I'd personally declare a simple user type to hold related values:

```
'Give this a more appropriate name.
Public Type Vector
    Akt As Double
    Immo As Double
    Short As Double
End Type
```

Then have `simulations` return an array of that:

```
Function simulations(k As Long) As Vector()
    Dim vectors() As Vector
    '...
    For l = 1 To Length
        ' write into the vectors
        vectors(l).Akt = zaktie
        vectors(l).Immo = zImmo
        vectors(l).Short = zshort
    Next l
    simulations = vectors
End Function
```

Finally, use the function's return value in your `Sub calculateColl`:

```
Sub calculateColl()
    Dim toWrite() As Vector
    toWrite = simulations(whateverKShouldBe)
    Dim l As Long
    Dim handle As Long
    handle = FreeFile
    Open "C\testfile.txt" For Append As #handle
    For l = LBound(toWrite) To UBound(toWrite)
        Print #handle, toWrite(l).Akt; ";"; toWrite(l).Immo; ";"; toWrite(l).Short
        Print #handle,
    Next l
    Close #handle
End Sub
```

Note that you should always use `FreeFile` instead of hard coded file numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not like i advise you to do this, but it should work if you declare them on module level, meaning right at the top of your module (under option explicit). E.g.

```
Option Explicit
Dim moAkt() as Single, moImmo() as Single, moShort() as Single

Sub simulations(k As Long)
.....
```

However, that's prone to error if you call your simulations-sub repeatedly.

Another more sophisticated approach would be change `Sub simulations` into a `Function` and return your arrays as a custom `Collection`

Comment: You are correct in saying that it will work, and you do explain having caution within your answer. But I want to re-emphasize the caution when using modular variables: **They can mess you up really badly if you are not careful!** I just recently suffered with this myself. Just keep an air of caution.

Comment: If I declare the vectors as Single there is still an error and the reason is that the sub is called repeatedly. Probably just the function can help